# Py2neo Api for Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I was playing around with `Py2neo`API for Neo4j , can somebody tell me how to pull the data from the `graph` by using `pull()` method. Can someone give me an example.

I did the following:

```
Node1=Node("Person",Name="Kartieya");
Graph().create(Node1);
Graph().pull(Node1);
```

I am recieving the status as 200 , i.e. its working but how i am going to get the Node1.Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push` and `pull` are only necessary for changes on existing nodes. `create` statements are carried out immediately.

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node
graph = Graph()

# note the trailing ',' for tuple unpacking
# 'create' can create more than one element at once
node1, = graph.create(Node("Person",Name="Kartieya"))
```

To get the `Name` property of your node do:

```
print node1.properties['Name']
```

If you now change a property you have to use push:

```
node1["new_prop"] = "some_value"
node1.push()
```

`pull` is only needed if properties of `node1` change on the server and you want to synchronize your local `node1` instance.